# How to run a progress bar on a timer - c#

Tags: c#, winforms, progress-bar

I want to run a progress bar on a form through the use of a timer.

I have tried multiple ways and have not been able to get it to work.

I hope someone here can help me with this.

```
private void SplashScreen_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        splashScreenTimer.Enabled = true;
        splashScreenTimer.Start();
        splashScreenTimer.Interval = 1000;
        progressBar.Maximum = 100;
        splashScreenTimer.Tick += new EventHandler(timer1_Tick);

    }

    private void timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (progressBar.Value != 10)
        {
            progressBar.Value++;
        }
        else
        {
            splashScreenTimer.Stop();
        }
    }
```

Comment: You have to post some code of what you've attempted.

Comment: i have updated the question, but would like it to work on a timer if possible

Comment: Show us the non-working timer code. There are plenty of examples of doing this on a timer on the web, and just giving you the code isn't really helping anyone

Comment: Like Grant said, I think this is what you want: `progressBar.Style = ProgressBarStyle.Marquee;`. It makes it animated without any timers.

Comment: i have changed the code in the question to something i also tried - this may be closer to what i am looking to acheive

Comment: So what's the problem with this code?

Comment: The progress bar is just not running

Comment: @ChrisDorman i've just repeated your code in empty WinForms application and all seems to work OK. I have a progressbar wich is filled to 10% in 10 seconds.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are assigning event_handler like

```
splashScreenTimer.Tick += new EventHandler(timer1_Tick);
```

and you are changing the progressBar value in

```
private void timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (progressBar.Value != 10)
    {
        progressBar.Value++;
    }
    else
    {
        splashScreenTimer.Stop();
    }
}
```

change event handler to

```
splashScreenTimer.Tick += new EventHandler(timer_Tick);
```

or move codes to the other event handler **timer1_Tick** which should be in your form

**For running the progressBar full in 4 seconds you can do like this**

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    splashScreenTimer.Enabled = true;
    splashScreenTimer.Start();
    splashScreenTimer.Interval = 30;
    progressBar.Maximum = 100;
    splashScreenTimer.Tick += new EventHandler(timer_Tick);
}

int waitingTime = 0;

private void timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (progressBar.Value < 100)
    {
        progressBar.Value++;
    }
    else
    {
        if (waitingTime++ > 35)
            this.Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, How do i get the progress bar to run smoothly?

Comment: Now i've answered your 3 questions, but you've not voted even once

Comment: Thank you for your help - although the progress bar is not reaching the end

Comment: Where you are putting the timer.Stop, i am using this.Close();

Comment: This isnt working, waitingTime is not getting increased anywhere

Comment: I've put **++** sign near to it. Didn't u see?

Comment: Maybe you've put the line **int waitingTime = 0;** inside the event

Comment: Check mine. I've put outside